# Typescript React map API response to internal type with extra properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I am building a react frontend client using typescript.  I would like to make a request to an api endpoint that will return a list of events.  When I get the response from this event I want to map it to an internal type, that will also have extra properties not returned from the API, specifically, I want to associate an icon to an internal type for when it is rendered.  The icon is not part of the API and I do not want it to be so it does not couple the front end to the API.  API response:

```
[
    {
        "identifier": "1",
        "name": "Gig"
    },
    {
        "identifier": "2",
        "name": "Concert"
    },
    {
        "identifier": "3",
        "name": "Some event type here"
    }
    {
        "identifier": "4",
        "name": "other"
    }
]
```

So I can request this fine, but I want to map that response back to an internal type of the following definition:

```
type Event = {
    identifier: string;
    name: string;
    icon: string;
}
```

Somewhere I want to map the returned labels from the API to an internal list that holds the corresponding icons.  I am not sure of the best way to do this, for that mapping to take place I will need an internal list of potential types that will be returned and the icons, or how to do that mapping?

Comment: just use switch case statement in component where u want to render icon component. for example when icon = "A" then render <A />, and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use interfaces that can inherit from another interface in this case. You can have 2 interfaces that can be used as your type.

```
interface Event{
    identifier: string;
    name: string;    
}

interface EventICON extends Event {
    icon: string;    
}
```

The `Event` interface can be used to map your API response and `EventICON` can be used after you inject your icon list inside the response you get.